# Field variable customization in node.tpl.php

Tags: entities

i have a website in which i am building a custom node page: `node--coupon.tpl.php` in which i want to render the body field only for which i used

> print render($content['body']);

The result is shown as "BODY: this is my text".

but i want to use only 'this is my text' which is entered at the time of making a new custom content type of coupon.

is it possible to do so anyhow?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide the label, go to Admin > Structure > Content types > Coupon > Manage display.

Comment: thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

Using render function will always render the whole stuff. Print the exact variable that contains the body content. If you are aware of [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module, it will hep you to find the exact variable.

For example, something like 
`print $node->body['und'][0]['value'];`
will do the stuff.Sure it will include the html tags ( if made entry ).